# sharing files through s2s connector

Tags: salesforce2salesforce

We have S2S connection establishment between two salesforce instances and its working fine without any issues.

In this S2S connection, we have a process to share the related records whenever we share the parent record from one salesforce to another salesforce instance. below is the code that I am using for sharing process.

> ```
>     //Preparing records to send using PartnerNetworkConnection
>     PartnerNetworkRecordConnection newrecord = new PartnerNetworkRecordConnection();
>     newrecord.ConnectionId = conn.Id;
>     newrecord.LocalRecordId = recordId;  
>     newrecord.SendClosedTasks = false;
>     newrecord.SendOpenTasks = false;
>     newrecord.SendEmails = false;
>     newrecord.RelatedRecords = 'Attachment';
>     insert newrecord;
> ```

Now we are changing the attachments to files and I do not see any option to send the Files as RelatedRecords through this process. I tried to change the newrecord.RelatedRecords = 'Attachment'; as

newrecord.RelatedRecords = 'ContentDocumentLink'; OR
newrecord.RelatedRecords = 'ContentDocument';

With this change, I am getting an error as,

> ContentDocument not related to SObject(basically related object)

I tried to find a solution through salesforce docs but I don't see any relevant information.
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_partnernetworkrecordconnection.htm

Does anyone know how to send files relatedlist in S2S connection?

Comment: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0874V000000lg6kQAA